# Why does my Infopath form take so long to render when opened from the the Task Assignment view?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath

After the Tasks to Approve, Complete, Acknowledge etc. is sent to the assigned user and they click on the link (ex. "NamedForm.xml") the form attempts to open but renders very slow.  The form will eventually open, but it takes several minutes before doing so.  Any reccomendations as to how I can speed this up?

Comment: Are you hitting any additional data connections with the form? Is the form opening in the browser or are they opening in the InfoPath client? What is your server load and configuration, are there a lot of users, are there more than one server, etc. Do you have problems with any other InfoPath forms. I know its a lot of additional questions, but it may help pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the article [Improving the Performance of InfoPath 2007 Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb380251.aspx) to see if there are any hints for you. Even though the title says 2007 it's still the recommended reading by Microsoft for 2010.

Comment: No additional data connections that I know of. Form is attmepting to open in with the client. As far as users, do you mean actively using the site or the form? One server being used. Every form I created has this rendering issue thus far. We are fairly new to the SharePoing scene so I hope I've answered your questions correctly.

Comment: My apologies Cory...I completely forgot the data connection to the library.  I configure the form to be submnitted to it's corresponding form library.

Comment: Per....I'm looking at your suggestions presently to see if it sheds any light on my sitution....thanks.